# Associated values in JPQL : Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a Entities as shown below.

**ThingType.java**

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ThingType {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "thing_type_id")
 private String thingTypeId;

 @Column(length = 50)
 private String description;

 @Embedded
 private Managed managed;

 @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,mappedBy = "thingType",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<ThingTypeBasicProperties> basicProperties = new ArrayList<>();

 @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,mappedBy = "thingType",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<ThingTypeMeasurementProperties> measurementProperties = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I have repository interface for ThingType.

ThingTypeRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ThingTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ThingType,String> {
 @Query(value = "select new io.badhusha.iotmonitor.model.ThingType(t.thingTypeId,t.description,bp,mp) from ThingType t LEFT JOIN t.basicProperties bp LEFT JOIN t.measurementProperties mp where t.thingTypeId = ?1")
Optional<ThingType> findThingTypeById(@NonNull String thingTypeId);
}
```

I am trying to fetch the **ThingType** with its associated **basicProperties** and **measurementProperties** using JPQL query.

I get error below

> Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [io.project.model.ThingType]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String, io.project.model.ThingTypeBasicProperties, io.project.model.ThingTypeMeasurementProperties

The error is saying it is expecting a single value of **ThingTypeBasicProperties** and **ThingTypeMeasurementProperties**. Why ? I am having a OneToMany relationship, it should be a List.

Can anyone please help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should rather use `t.basicProperties` and `t.measurementProperties` to bind the `List` instances. Give a try the following query:

```
@Query(value = 
        "select new" + 
        "io.badhusha.iotmonitor.model.ThingType(" +
            "t.thingTypeId, t.description, t.basicProperties, t.measurementProperties" +
        ")" +
        "from ThingType t" +
        "left join t.basicProperties" +
        "left join t.measurementProperties" +
        "where t.thingTypeId = ?1")
```

```java
"select new io.badhusha.iotmonitor.model.ThingType(t.thingTypeId, t.description, t.basicProperties, t.measurementProperties) from ThingType t LEFT JOIN t.basicProperties LEFT JOIN t.measurementProperties where t.thingTypeId = ?1"
```

Finally, your constructor generated with `@AllArgsConstructor` contains 5 parameters (with `Managed` as the 3rd parameter). You need to define new constructor matching:

```
(String, String, List<ThingTypeBasicProperties>, List<ThingTypeMeasurementProperties>)
```

Comment: Now I am getting an different error
**Unable to locate appropriate constructor Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Collection, java.util.Collection**